# Linq match string list and string value

Tags: c#, linq

I used below code

```
 string userList = string.Join(",", db.UserRole.Where(p => p.FirmUserID == 1).Select(p => p.RoleID.ToString()));
```

**userList** values below,

```
1,12,17,33,76
```

I have also below string list

```
List<string> roleList = new List<string>();
roleList.add("14");
rolelist.add("33");
roleList.add("76");
```

How can i check userList includes roleList value and get matches value in entity framework ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're keeping the user list as a single string rather than as a list? And any reason why you're using strings for values which look like they're all numbers?

Comment: not really if you can suggest matcihng for list i can apply on my side thanks for help and realize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all instead of converting your userList to string keep it as a List

```
List<string> userList = db.UserRole.Where(p => p.FirmUserID == 1).Select(p => p.RoleID.ToString()).Tolist();
```

To check if userList **includes** roleList

```
bool doesInclude = !roleList .Except(userList).Any();
```

to get the matches:

```
List<string> matches = userList.Intersect(roleList).ToList();
```

But if this is what you need to accomplish you'd better work sith integer types instead of string, because string comparison is more error prone (by the user).